# Angular - How to set up interface for tree structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, interface, tree

I'm trying to set up an interface relatively to [this api](https://bgpie.net/api/sequence/5ee56984a62b68061ce5b638). Every property is read except for `asTreeWithoutAggregator`, as you can see it's a tree structure where a node either has a name and a value or a name and children. This is how i set up the interface.

```
import { TreeNode } from './treeNode';
export interface Sequence{
  id: string;
  prefix: string;
  rRC: number;
  collectorPeer: {
    peerBGPId: number;
    peerIPAddress: string;
    peerAS: number;
  };
  start: string;
  end: string;
  runID: string;
  longestCommonAsPathSuffix: number;
  asPathNumber: number;
  asOrigins: number;
  hasAggregator: boolean;
  containsAsPathLoops: boolean;
  containsLoops: boolean;
  mostFrequentUpdateFrequency: number;
  mostFrequentUpdateFrequencyInMin: number;
  hasAsPathsNotValid: boolean;
  asTreeWithoutAggregator: {
    head: TreeNode;
  };
  announces: number;
  withdraws: number;
  updates: number;
  duration: string;
  frequency: number;
}
```

Where `TreeNode` is:

```
export interface TreeNode {
    name: string;
    children: TreeNode[];
    value: (number | null);
}
```

I've also tried defining it like this:

```
  asTreeWithoutAggregator: {
    head: (TreeNodeWithValue|TreeNodeWithChildren);
  };

  export interface TreeNode{
    name: string;
  }

  export interface TreeNodeWithValue extends TreeNode: {
    value: number;
  }

  export interface TreeNodeWithChildren extends TreeNode {
    children: (TreeNodeWithValue|TreeNodeWithChidren)[]
```

Comment: i don't see any problem with your implementation ? does you have error when compile or run ?

Comment: no, everything is good